# let in if without braces

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
if (true) {
  let x = 5
}
```

works as expected (no syntax error), but

```
if (true) let x = 5
```

throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word` in Node 4.1.0 and babel

Is this expected behavior? I know that this is a stupid example. I'm just wondering wether this is a bug or not.

Comment: Because `let` is block-based and the above isn't a block, I assume an error is inevitable. You would not be able to use the `let` after this declaration anyway as this is a single-line 'block'.

Comment: This makes sense if you think about it. Even though there *is* a block scope here, what good is a block scoped variable in it? Because you can never use it

Comment: OK, expected and reasonable behavior. Thanks.

Comment: When I try that in Firefox I get an error message that is more to the point: `SyntaxError: lexical declaration not directly within block`.

Comment: @Guffa thats definitely a better error message.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue what about in the case of a callback, e.g. something like: `let server = app.listen(() => console.log(server.address()))`? The callback has access to the variable.

Comment: @Inkling You're right, I should have said "you can never use it outside of the block". While that is a minor use case, you'd need to ask yourself why that code is structured to produce unused variables. The callback should provide whatever state it needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is expected behavior. [The production rule of an `if` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement) is

```
 if ( Expression[In, ?Yield] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Return]
```

but a `let` declaration [is not a `Statement`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) and is therefore not allowed in this position:

```
Statement[Yield, Return] :
    BlockStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    VariableStatement[?Yield]
    EmptyStatement
    ExpressionStatement[?Yield]
    IfStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    BreakableStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    ContinueStatement[?Yield]
    BreakStatement[?Yield]
    [+Return] ReturnStatement[?Yield]
    WithStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    LabelledStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    ThrowStatement[?Yield]
    TryStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
    DebuggerStatement

Declaration[Yield] :
    HoistableDeclaration[?Yield]
    ClassDeclaration[?Yield]
    LexicalDeclaration[In, ?Yield]

LexicalDeclaration[In, Yield] :
    LetOrConst BindingList[?In, ?Yield] ;
```

Comment: The duplicate [Error: 'let' declarations can only be declared inside a block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37164548/1344955) has answers that contain practical examples in addition to this explanation.