# Error: 'let' declarations can only be declared inside a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

In my project I have these lines:

```
if (text.length > 0) {
    let data = "Some value";
}
```

Because there is only one statement inside the `if`, I wanted to remove the brackets (`{ }`). My code then would have looked like this:

```
if (text.length > 0)
    let data = "Some value";
```

However I got the following error:

> 'let' declarations can only be declared inside a block.

Every other single statement inside `if` works fine without the brackets. Why do I get this error?

Comment: What is the reason you want to use let there? It won't be visible outside this if statement.

Comment: @Andrey That answer is far too technical and cryptic, if anything, that should be marked as a dupe of this question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared by let have as their scope the block in which they are defined, so you need the brackets to define the scope.
You can use let to establish variables that are scoped only to a single expression:

```
var a = 5;
let(a = 6) console.log(a); // 6
console.log(a); // 5
```

Note: *let expression* and *let block* are Non-standard let extensions and their support has been dropped.

Comment: `let(a = 6) console.log(a)` This isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: You mean it is a Non-standard but is valid

Comment: It isn't. See [MDN Non-standard let extensions -> let expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_expressions) for further info - this syntax was proposed but it's was dropped from spec.

Comment: It doesn't work any more in Firefox 44+ and never worked for IE or Chrome

Comment: I will make an edit to note it then

Answer (score 2):

Because 'let' declarations can only be declared inside a block.

In fact, such code is useless, because `let` and `const` are block-scoped.

```
if (foo) {
   let bar = true;
}
bar // bar doesn't exist here;
```

So even if your would be legal, it wouldn't work - so it's forbidden.

Comment: A situation where the variable would not be useless: `let server = app.listen(() => console.log(server.address()))`. Yes this works (until you try to use it with a single-line `if`).